# Very small OpenCL work group size for Nvidia GTX 970

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I have a NVidia GTX 970 card and is doing some OpenCL. I use clGetDeviceInfo to get some values and strangely, I only get a maximum work size of 13. 
(CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE=13). Isn't it should be 512 or 1024? Here is my code:

```
int queryInt;
int queryDim[3] = {0,0,0};
cl_int clError;
clError = clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_NAME, sizeof(queryBuffer), &queryBuffer, NULL);
printf("CL_DEVICE_NAME: %s\n", queryBuffer);
queryBuffer[0] = '\0';
clError = clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_VENDOR, sizeof(queryBuffer), &queryBuffer, NULL);
printf("CL_DEVICE_VENDOR: %s\n", queryBuffer);
queryBuffer[0] = '\0';
clError = clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DRIVER_VERSION, sizeof(queryBuffer), &queryBuffer, NULL);
printf("CL_DRIVER_VERSION: %s\n", queryBuffer);
queryBuffer[0] = '\0';
clError = clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_VERSION, sizeof(queryBuffer), &queryBuffer, NULL);
printf("CL_DEVICE_VERSION: %s\n", queryBuffer);
queryBuffer[0] = '\0';
clError = clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(int), &queryInt, NULL);
printf("CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS: %d\n", queryInt);
clError = clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(int), &queryInt, NULL);
printf("CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: %d\n", queryInt);
max_work_items = queryInt;
clError = clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES, 3*sizeof(int), queryDim, NULL);
printf("CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES: (%d %d %d)\n", queryDim[0], queryDim[1], queryDim[2]);
```

and the result:

```
CL_DEVICE_NAME: GeForce GTX 970
CL_DEVICE_VENDOR: NVIDIA Corporation
CL_DRIVER_VERSION: 346.59
CL_DEVICE_VERSION: OpenCL 1.1 CUDA
CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS: 13
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: 13
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES: (0 0 0)
```

Comment: For your information, there is a Game Dev specific site on the StackExchange network: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/  This question may fit there better.

Comment: You should check if one of the previous calls causes an error.  It's a strange coincidence that it prints the same number as in the line before (for the `MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS`). For me, it prints 1024 on my GTX970. Also note that you should use a `size_t` and not an `int` for some of these calls.

Comment: @jwatts1980, there is nothing related to game development in this question; OpenCL is a general accelerated compute API

Comment: @Macro13: Thank you. Indeed, changing from int to size_t solves my problem.